# How do I print from Outlook.com Calendar

Tags: outlook.com

I have recently switched my Hotmail account to Outlook.com and I am using the [Calendar](http://calendar.live.com) app. How can I print a list of events (or the week or month view) from within Outlook.com. I am using Google Chrome on Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be either a print option or a print `CSS` file either at the time of writing. If you try to use the web browsers print feature, it comes up with essentially a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [response from Microsoft](https://twitter.com/MicrosoftHelps/status/330687059603886080) states that the feature isn't available, and that one of the workarounds is to sync the calendar to Microsoft Outlook so it can be printed there

If you don't want to use Outlook, no doubt you can export the calendar and print it in whatever calendar application you use

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to print a weekly or monthly Outlook.com calendar list from Chrome, my preferred browser. When I want to do that, I access Outlook.com from the Internet Explorer browser and select "Agenda" from the View dropdown menu in the OUtlook upper right corner. Then click File > Print Preview on the IE Menu Bar and choose desirable a print size. Then click the print icon.

Answer (score -2):

If you take a screen grab then paste it into paint it will print.